Tesseract OCR through pytesseract image_to_string method config field not doing anything
The config field of the mentioned method has no affect on the output.  I am trying to recognize a single digit (0-9) from a photo.
I will make the page segmentation mode 10 (single character mode) by adding '--psm 10' and do a bunch of other things but it just doesn't have an effect.  Ill use the whitelist or blacklist to only include numbers, and it just doesn't do that, letters are still included.
Here is the usage:
pytesseract.image_to_string(im_bw, config='--psm 6''-c tessesdit''_char_whitelist=0987654321''-1 osd''outputbase digits')

I've tried --psm 6 and --psm 10 but neither do what they are supposed to.
